# Hibernate. Session.get(type, id) returns null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session, get

I'm having a problem with Hibernate in our project.
Session.get() method returns null, although the object with the needed id does exist in database.

```
Long geocodedLocationId = geocoderService.geocode(latitude, longitude);
GeocodedLocation geocodedLocation = (geocodedLocationId != null) ? geocodedLocationService.read(geocodedLocationId) : null;
```

First line is calling the GeocoderService using RMI, the GeocoderService geocodes the latitude/longitude and creates a GeocodedLocation object that is saved in table "geocoded_locations".

After this, if GeocoderService returned an ID, we will load the object from database and use it.

The problem is that GeocoderService returns the ID, but Hibernate is unable to find the object by id in database.

But When I run the program again for the same latitude and longitude, it returns the same ID, and Hibernate is able to find the object in database. So it's only failing for recently created GeocodedLocations.

I tried stopping in the debugger right after the first line. So I can check the returned ID, and check it in mysql, so I see that the needed object really does exist there. But when I'm trying to load it by ID, Hibernate can't do it (So I think the problem is not that GeocoderService hasn't flushed the session, as I can see that the GeocodedLocation has already been saved to database).

Additional information:
read() method implementation:

```
@Override
public T read(PK id) {
    T returnValue = (T) factory.getCurrentSession().get(type, id);
    return returnValue;
}
```

"type" is GeocodedLocation.class, "id" is a Long value.

The query that is being executed when trying to get an object by id is the following:

```
 Hibernate: 
    /* load com.my.domain.businessObjects.GeocodedLocation */ select
        geocodedlo0_.id as id30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.building_number_name as building2_30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.street as street30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.town_city as town4_30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.region as region30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.postcode as postcode30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.state as state30_0_,
        geocodedlo0_.country as country30_0_ 
    from
        db_production.geocoded_locations geocodedlo0_ 
    where
        geocodedlo0_.id=?
```

Comment: This is rather late, but I'm guessing your transaction isolation level prevents you from reading that data. check your transaction settings. Impossible to say for sure from your code sample.